# Change global variable contents without influencing the other variable contents

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm try to use the LLVM api (inside my own pass) to change the contents of the g_Meh1 variable.

```
const char g_Meh1[] = "++__BLA__";
const char g_Meh2[] = "++__BLA__";

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s", gMeh1);
    printf("%s", gMeh2);
}
```

I've created a LLVM pass and I want to change the body of one variable (ie. g_Meh1) but apparently those two global variable share the same initializer (var_data and var_org_data point to the same memory). When I am changing the data of the g_Meh1 the data of g_Meh2 changes as well - i don't want to do that.

Even though the function below will be only done one time the contents of both variables will be changed

```
ConstantDataSequential *var_data = dyn_cast<ConstantDataSequential>(glob_var1->getInitializer());
char *var_org_data              = (char*)var_data->getRawDataValues().data();
var_org_data[0] = 'A'; // change first byte
```

I've tried to provide new initializer for the each variable, but LLVM brings assert condition that the types does not match.

```
StringRef StrVal = StringRef("BLA12", 6);                 
char *Data = (char*)StrVal.begin();
int Size = StrVal.size();

                      
Constant *test = ConstantDataArray::getString(M.getContext(), StringRef(Data, Size), false);    

var_dupl->setInitializer(test); // assert triggered, type mismatch
```

Any ideas how to solve it?